# How can I change the "offer ends" text to spanish?

Tags: wordpress

[image]

Please guide me on where to change the code, I could not understand it.

Comment: Hi Fatima. It´s going to be a little difficult to provide suggestions unless we get some more details from you. Please read this and then edit your question so we can help: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What theme do you use? Is this section added by plugin or theme?

Comment: porto theme. You can see this link : https://juegosdigitalescolombia.com.co/

Answer (score 0):

In each theme, it can be placed in different files. You can download your theme to your computer and through Notepad ++, for example, search the theme files for this phrase OFFER ENDS. So you will see in which file it is located and you will calmly edit it through the editor.

Comment: if ( $date_diff ) {
   echo '<div class="sale-product-daily-deal' . $extra_class . '"' . ( $extra_class ? ' style="display: none"' : '' ) . '>';
    echo '<h5 class="daily-deal-title">' . esc_html__( 'Offer Ends In:', 'porto' ) . '</h5>';

Comment: I cannot override this in child theme